# DLL Injection Static Pointer Different Value

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, bots, dll-injection

I am trying to write a bot for a game, with a DLL Injection. I have found a static pointer to an address I want to read from the DLL.

The static pointer's address is wow64cpu.dll+4738, which I get with cheat engine by:

1. Finding the value (z coordinate of character)
2. Choosing "Find out what accesses this address"
3. Copying the easy guess and searching for it
4. And now I have this pointer

The problem is, if I close the game and reopen it, and then view what is at the address wow64cpu.dll+4738, cheat engine gives me 4294967294 (which is 0xFFFFFFFE)

If I find the z coordinate value again, and then do the debugging again to find the static pointer, I get a correct value.

I can't figure out why this happens, and I have been looking for almost a week now...

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Hello. Could you please rephrase the problem. I did not understand, what is going wrong specifically? Are You saying that the pointer offset changes across game restarts? Can You write a piece of code that finds the pointer automatically based on some patterns in data instead of You searching for it manually?

Comment: @RolandPihlakas Exactly. The static pointer value changes to FFFFFE when the game restarts.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas And then when I run the cheat engine debugger, the value changes.